# Download multiple txt files R

Tags: r, download, quanteda

I want to download a number of .txt-files. I have a data frame'"New_test in which the urls are under 'url' and the dest. names under 'code

"New_test.txt"

```
"url"   "code"
"1" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/704931468739539459/text/multi-page.txt" "704931468739539459.txt"
"2" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/239491468743788559/text/multi-page.txt"  "239491468743788559.txt"
"3" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/489381468771867920/text/multi-page.txt"  "489381468771867920.txt"
"4" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/663271468778456388/text/multi-page.txt"  "663271468778456388.txt"
"5" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/330661468742793711/text/multi-page.txt"  "330661468742793711.txt"
"6" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/120441468766519490/text/multi-page.txt"  "120441468766519490.txt"
"7" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/901481468770727038/text/multi-page.txt"  "901481468770727038.txt"
"8" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/172351468740162422/text/multi-page.txt"  "172351468740162422.txt"
"9" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/980401468740176249/text/multi-page.txt"  "980401468740176249.txt"
"10" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/166921468759906515/text/multi-page.txt" "166921468759906515.txt"
"11" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/681071468781809792/text/DRD169.txt" "681071468781809792.txt"
"12" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/358291468739333041/text/multi-page.txt" "358291468739333041.txt"
"13" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/716041468759870921/text/multi0page.txt" "716041468759870921.txt"
"14" "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/961101468763752879/text/34896.txt"  "961101468763752879.txt"`
```

this is the script

```
rm(list=ls())

require(quanteda)
library(stringr)

workingdir <-setwd("~/Study/Master/Thesis/Mining/R/WorldBankDownl") 
test <- read.csv(paste0(workingdir,"/New_test.txt"), header = TRUE, 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep="\t")

#Loop through every url in test_df and download in target directory with name = code
 for (url in test) {
 print(head(url))
 print(head(test$code))
 destfile <- paste0('~/Study/Master/Thesis/Mining/R/WorldBankDownl/Sources/', test$code)
 download.file(test$url, destfile,  method = "wget", quiet=TRUE)
```

And this is the error I get

```
Error in download.file(test$url, destfile, method = "wget", quiet = TRUE) : 
'url' must be a length-one character vector
```

Comment: try changing: "for (url in test)" to: "for url in test$code" and also "download.file(test$url" to "download.file(url"

Comment: Thank you for your reply. "for (url in test$code)", -without the ( the loop doesn't work- gives the error: Error in download.file(url, destfile, method = "wget", quiet = TRUE) : 
  'destfile' must be a length-one character vector

Comment: u also need to change the second part i mentioned (i.e., change download.file(test$url to download.file(url

Comment: download.file(url, destfile, method = "wget", quiet = TRUE)

Comment: Sorry I was interrupted, yes I had changed the second part as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone, thank you for helping me. For me the solution was changing the method I used. 'wget' demanded 1 url in 'url' and the same for 'destfile'. 'A length-one character vector' Both 'url' and 'destfile' are length-fourteen character vectors. Now I use the method 'libcurl', which demands that the length of the character vectors is equal in 'url' and 'destfile'. If you use this method, make sure that quiet = TRUE.

Furthermore, it is possible that you have a working loop but that you get the error.

```
Error in download.file(test$url, destfile, method = "libcurl", quiet = TRUE) : 
cannot download any files
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

This means that your source can't keep up with your calls, you're basically DDOS'ing, so the loop has to be slowed down.

```
rm(list=ls())

require(quanteda)
library(stringr)

workingdir <-setwd("~/Study/Master/Thesis/Mining/R/WorldBankDownl") 
test <- read.csv(paste0(workingdir,"/New_test.txt"), header = TRUE, 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep="\t")

test <- data.frame(test)


#Loop through every url in comb_df and download in target directory with name = code, if you get an error and no files are downloaded try to slow down the loop.
for (url in test) {
 print(head(url))
 destfile <- paste0(workingdir, '/Sources/WB_', test$code)
 download.file(test$url, destfile, method = "libcurl", quiet = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it that is a bit simpler.  You will need to substitute your `test$url` for the `txturls` (both are character vectors with the URL of the text file).

```
txturls <- c("http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/704931468739539459/text/multi-page.txt", 
             "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/239491468743788559/text/multi-page.txt",
             "http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/489381468771867920/text/multi-page.txt")

library("quanteda")

txt <- character()
for (i in txturls) {
    # read the file from the URL
    temp <- readLines(url("http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/704931468739539459/text/multi-page.txt"))
    # concatenate lines into one text
    temp <- texts(temp, groups = 1)
    # remove form feed character
    txt <- gsub("\\f", "", txt)
    # concatenate into the vector
    txt <- c(txt, temp)
}

# form the quanteda corpus
urlcorp <- corpus(txt, docvars = data.frame(source = txturls, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
summary(urlcorp)
# Corpus consisting of 3 documents:
# 
#  Text Types Tokens Sentences                                                                           source
#     1  1343   5125       135 http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/704931468739539459/text/multi-page.txt
#   1.1  1343   5125       135 http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/239491468743788559/text/multi-page.txt
#   1.2  1343   5125       135 http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/489381468771867920/text/multi-page.txt
# 
# Source: /Users/kbenoit/Dropbox (Personal)/GitHub/dictionaries_paper/* on x86_64 by kbenoit
# Created: Tue Mar 20 15:51:05 2018
# Notes:
```

Comment: Thank you. I assigned test to txturl. test <- read.csv("~/Study/Master/Thesis/Mining/R/WorldBankDownl/total_txt.txt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep="\t")


txturls <- c(test) Then I got the error Error: nrow(docvars) == length(x) is not TRUE

Comment: I meant you want to use `test$url` where I have used `txturls`. The object over whose elements you are looping in the for loop needs to be a character vector containing the URLs of the files to be read.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work. I now assume that it was due to overcalling the source. In the meantime, I found a solution to my problem, but your solution looks neater. So I'll try to implement this.